# Use full month names instead of short ones

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Use "December" instead of "Dec".
"December" is more user friendly. Why you need to short it?

Edit: My ayes look for full names. I've never used the short ones. (And I'm trilingual)

Comment: .. short it where?

Comment: above the username in the questions and answers

Comment: I don't see how it's user friendly. Yes, it is a bit clearer but you're going to end up breaking the UI.

Comment: You and I both knew that it was "December". Seems sufficiently user friendly.

Comment: I'd rather have ISO dates myself (yyyy-mm-dd). Universal, string sortable...

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea as I think it decreases readability. Any of the breaks interface arguments seem a bit pointless to me

Comment: On StackOverflow it should be displayed as seconds since midnight 1/1/1970, using 64-bits of course. That should be clear enough for any programmer. For the programming-impaired, there's a greasemonkey script you can use to convert to non-programmer date strings.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Having the full month perhaps marginally improves the readability. For that, you get a broken layout - not very ideal.

[image: Full Month]

Comment: I don't agree with the request, but I'm also not getting the argument that it has to break the UI. The UI is mutable, it can be adapted easily, in a number of ways.

Comment: @Wesley: The "Your Answer" box is just begging for your suggestion on how to do that. I, for one, don't think that the signature box ought to get any *bigger* than it already is, so I'm interested in how you'd alter the UI to fit more information given that constraint.

Comment: @Cody: It doesn't really make sense for me to answer, with ideas on how to fit it in the UI, if I don't support the proposal, but for example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DJAyq.png

Comment: "2009"? you broke it on purpose. -1

Comment: @NickDandoulakis it's still broken with '09. --> http://i.imgur.com/8FCRA.png

Comment: Sathya I was kidding :)

Comment: @NickDandoulakis :( #Self #Fail

Answer (score 2):

The box is not large enough to fit all the full name months:

See the very basic example here :

[image: Measure]

### Edit

In fact it could work on some sites like gaming:

[image: Gaming.se]

But not meta:

[image: Meta.se]

Also I don't really see the point of having full names printed. Anyone can understand it with a little. In the same way, we should write the year in full format: 2010? I'll stick to the K.I.S.S. paradigm.

Comment: I prefer to have the year spelled out in full, as in "Two thousand ten".

Comment: @Wesley: *"I have hereunto set my hand and caused the Seal of <<User Name>> to be affixed this 17th day of December in the year of our Lord two thousand ten."*

Comment: @Cody: That works, just add in the microseconds, moon phase, and dew point and I think we've got all the information we need.